# Why Spring JPA Mysql data connection can be initialized properly in IntelliJ but not on command line?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I have the following gradle dependencies:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27'
```

My application-local.yaml has the following: (edited the typo in the yml file name)

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/local_test
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I built and ran my application on IntelliJ (just run my main class `MainApplication` that has `SpringApplication.run`) and the connection works. I checked the command behind the scene used by IntelliJ, it's like this:

```
<jvmdirectory>/Contents/Home/bin/java 
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 
-noverify 
-Dspring.profiles.active=local 
-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always 
-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=58413:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dspring.jmx.enabled=true 
-Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain 
-Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-classpath <many jar files here, some come from ~/.gradle/caches/, some come from my app directory .out/lib/> com.x.MainApplication 
--logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml
```

It runs and there is no error initializing the Hibernate/JPA/Database bean setup.

However, if I run them on my command line (which I will have to do later because I will be running it on Docker), it won't proceed beyond datasource initialization. This is the command I used:

```
java \
 -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify \
 -Dspring.config.activate.on-profile=local \
 -Duser.timezone=UTC \
 -jar .out/libs/app-x-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
 --logging.config="classpath:log4j2.xml" \
```

It gives this very common error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-12-18T17:41:53,080Z",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "thread": "main",
  "message": "

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:tIf you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
\tIf you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles x are currently active).
",
  "logger": "org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter"
}
```

There are many SO posts about this error and everyone suggests to exclude `DatasourceAutoConfiguration.class` but to be honest, I don't understand this well (no one really explained what it does and why excluding it) and I don't know if excluding it is right for me. I do want the datasource to initiate at Spring app startup time.

There two parts to my question:

1. Why running the app via IntelliJ and command line differ so much in behavior?
2. Should I exclude DatasourceAutoConfiguration.class like everybody else does? If so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your problem is not simply related to your applcation-dev.yml being loaded rather than application.yml ?

Comment: @NoDataFound sorry, typo, i loaded application-local.yml. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
Use `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` instead of `-Dspring.config.activate.on-profile=local`.

I have no idea why this works. If someone knows, please respond to this answer.

Also, I do not need to exclude `DatasourceAutoConfiguration.class`.

Comment: From how i understand the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.activation-properties, `spring.config.activate.on-profile` should be used within a specific YAML document to activate that document on that condition. So using it on the command line doesn't have any effect. `spring.profiles.active` is specifically for configuring active profiles.